# Trouble capturing command output

Tags: bash, shell-script, io-redirection

I'm having some trouble capturing the output of a command in Bash.

I have a Bash script to test a C program...

```
bufsize=1
while [ $bufsize -le 16384 ]
do
    runtime=$(/usr/bin/time -f "%e" -o /dev/tty \
    ./raw_copy $bufsize ./country_vaccinations.csv raw_copy.out)
    
    echo "Runtime for array with $bufsize slots was $runtime."
    
    bufsize=$(( $bufsize * 2 ))
done
```

(it tests how fast the program `raw_copy`, which we wrote, copies a file, based on how much memory the program is allowed to use. This is an assignment.)

I've tried a few different variants of capturing the output of the `time` command into the variable called `runtime`. E.g., `runtime=$(stuff)` as above, `runtime="$(stuff)"`, and also varying the quotes in the `echo` command. However I can't quite get what I'm looking for. The output I keep getting is

```
$ ./test4.sh 
0.60
Runtime for array with 1 slots was .
0.30
Runtime for array with 2 slots was .
0.15
Runtime for array with 4 slots was .
0.07
Runtime for array with 8 slots was .
0.04
Runtime for array with 16 slots was .
0.01
Runtime for array with 32 slots was .
0.01
Runtime for array with 64 slots was .

(et cetera)
```

and as you may be able to tell I'm looking for something more like

```
$ ./test4.sh
Runtime for array with 1 slots was 0.60.
Runtime for array with 2 slots was 0.30.

(et cetera)
```

Just thought I'd see if someone could help me out.
(So essentially I'm just having a hard time figuring out how to save the output of the `time` command into a variable, instead of just printing it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default at least the `time` on my Debian outputs to stderr, which isn't good using it in a command substitution. Though in your command, you're telling it to print to `/dev/tty`, directly to the terminal, which also doesn't work.

Tell it to print to `/dev/stdout` instead:

```
t=$(/usr/bin/time -f "%e" -o /dev/stdout sleep 1)
echo "that took $t s"
```

or, with a redirection in the shell:

```
t=$(/usr/bin/time -f "%e" sleep 1 2>&1)
```

Comment: Awesome, that does just what I'm looking for. Apparently I need to learn a little about tty versus stdout. Thanks.